# Showing an image on screen attached to Pi via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, image

I am running a raspberry pi3b+ via ssh. There is a hyperpixel4 screen by Pimoroni attached to the Pi and it's working fine. I am trying to display an image on the screen attached to the Pi with a python script via SSH.

I tried PIL and Pygame, but none works.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("image.jpg")
img.show()


import pygame #voor beeld en geluid
from time import sleep
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 800
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 0)
img = pygame.image.load("ndvi.jpg")
windowSurface.blit(img, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

With PIL, nothing happens at all. Even if I don't use SSH and type directly into the Pi's terminal.
Pygame works if I type directly into the Pi (with a delay, but that can be solved with subprocess maybe). But it shows this error via ssh-"Unable to open a console terminal".

Thanks

Comment: Does the image is shown if you are direct logged in to the RasPi using an attached keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your python script, run this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It wakes up the display in case it has turned off due to inactivity. But it doesn't show the image.

Comment: What if you do `export DISPLAY=:0.0` ?